# Is there a way to improve `cosinor` model

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to improve the fitting data with *cosinor* model.

I read some articles where I found that I can use a composite model (24 h cosine fit and 12 h cosine fit) but I didn't find the best fitting results. I also tried `catCosinor` but I didn't get the best result.

```
library("cosinor")

cosinor_Model <- cosinor.lm(moyenne_Temperature ~ time(hour) ,period = 21, data = mean_Temperature_H_Alldays ) 

summary(cosinor_Model) 

ggplot.cosinor.lm(cosinor_Model)+ geom_line(data=mean_Temperature_H_Alldays,aes(x=hour,y=moyenne_Temperature,color=factor(Id)))
```

I want my curve to fit my data as well as possible. 
Here is my data set:

```
structure(list(Id = structure(c(16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L), .Label = c("110f", "118d", "122c", "122f", "1231", "124b", "1265", "134b", "139f", "1524", "1643", "165b", "3.60E+04", "308d", "323a", "3270", "3343", "3390", "3393", "346e", "354f", "3626", "3707", "381a"), class = "factor"), hour = 0:23, moyenne_Temperature = c(39.1594557823129, 39.1343750000001, 39.1696688741722, 39.2040760869565, 39.2164609053498, 39.1516000000001, 39.2884979702301, 39.5986719787517, 39.6836849507736, 39.5314049586777, 39.3539528432732, 39.3680272108844, 39.4646746347942, 39.6108815426998, 39.5880272108844, 39.4295546558705, 39.211659807956, 39.1260107816711, 39.109561752988, 39.0975388601036, 39.1241469816273, 39.1317523056653, 39.1495238095238, 39.1721194879089)), row.names = c(NA, -24L ), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000009301ef0>)
```

Here is what I get:

[image: cosinor fit]

Comment: Ow sorry @Roland, I did not see it was time series data. My fault. I thought it was just a distribution. I would try in that case  a two-variable Gaussian distribution. Nevertheless, I am not able to explain it well, so for that reason I will just delete my answer. I would consider moving this question to stats.exchange, since it seems more apropiate there.

Comment: ok.thanks but i didn't find stats.exchange on google. anyway if you can send me the link i will move my question there.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's hard to help you  otherwise.

Comment: Ok.you can find it under my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use multiple components with catCosinor and i find something a little bit good. Thanks to everyone.[image: multiple components with catCosinor]